# Where is the SSH RSA modulus actually sent?

Tags: rsa

This might be a stupid question but: When RSA key pairs are generated, there is a pubkey and a private key file. Where is the modulus? Is it appended to the keys? I can't find any information about that.

Comment: Suppose that your folder to receive Key pair is "MyLoc"
$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/MyLoc/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /Users/MyLoc/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/MyLoc/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
... You can't edit the key pair.The data is encrypted with the passphrase you entered.
Take a look here: https://git-scm.com/book/fr/v1/Git-sur-le-serveur-G%C3%A9n%C3%A9ration-des-cl%C3%A9s-publiques-SSH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modulus is part of the public key. For RSA, the public key consists of the pair $(n,e)$ where $n$ is the modulus and $e$ is the public exponent.

The SSH public key file contains both, typically one after the other. There's a number of ways to encode this information. The gory details of these encodings I leave to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193529/how-to-store-retrieve-rsa-public-private-key/13104466#13104466) in-depth answer (it includes a section on SSH).

The SSH private key file contains pretty much all numbers associated with the key generation process. If you want to take a look yourself, try running the following command

```
openssl rsa -in test.key -text
```

where `test.key` is your private key file.

Comment: Ah I see. The private key just stores the primes so the chinese remainder theorem can be applied. The layout is indeed gory. I wonder why they didn't just concatenate the values. Btw, what is the coefficient used for?

Comment: @AdHominem: 'coefficient' is $q^{-1} \mod p$ and used in the CRT calcuation; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29#Example . Note this answer is about (locally) _stored_ keys, as the body of your Q seems to be (but only for OpenSSH, other implementations are different); for keys _sent_ in the (current) protocol as in the title of your Q, see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4253#section-6.6 .

Comment: You could of course recalculate it, but I would say that the modulus is part of the private key *as well*.